# PHP file update cannot takeplace

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to update and upload image to folder using php fileupload also some contents in the text area and text field. Here is my code,problem is I am not getting any result from the database. Please help.

```
$id=(isset($_GET['id']))?$_GET['id']:'';
$val=view_data_event($id);
if (isset($_POST["events"])&&isset($_POST["description"])) 
{
    $id=$_POST["id"]; 
    $title=$_POST["events"];
    $description=$_POST["description"];
    $filetmp=$_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"];
    $filename=$_FILES["images"]["name"];
    $filetype=$_FILES["images"]["type"];
    $filepath= "photo2/".$filename;
    move_uploaded_file( $filetmp,$filepath);
    $data=array( $title,$description,$filename,$filepath,$id);
    $update1=update_event($data);
    if($update1)
    {
        echo "<script>location.href='hotel2_galery_event.php'</script>";
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="hotel2_galery_eventedit.php" method="post" class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
    <div class="form-group has-info">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess">Event title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="events" value="">
    </div>                                   
    <div class="form-group has-info">
        <label>Event Description</label>
        <textarea name="description" class="form-control " rows="3">
        </textarea><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-info">
        <label>Event Related images</label>
        <input type="file" name="images">
        <input type="hidden" value="">
        <input type="hidden" value="">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span>UPDATE</span>
    </button> 
</form>
```

Comment: show me `update_event($data)` function

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to upload files, you must put a `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute on the `form` tag. Standard POST encoding cannot handle files.

Comment: I got an error message as Array to string conversion and cannot update. Please help.